# Can you make a Rectangle from an Odd Number of Triangles?

Tags: geometry

So, the triangles are the same size, they are equilateral triangles. Can you use an odd number of these, to create a rectangle? If so how many, if possible post an image of your answer!

Answer with the least amount of triangles gets Best Answer

Comment: I can't even see how you could make a rectangle with any number of equilateral triangles.

Comment: The answer is: no.

Comment: @itdoesntwork draw a square, draw an X through it

Comment: @RedAlert Those wouldn't be equilateral.

Comment: Since a rectangle requires 90-degree corners, and every angle inside an equilateral triangle is 60-degrees, it's impossible. The only multiple of 90 that you can make is 180-degrees (or any multiple of it). You can make rhombs, but no rectangles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honest answer: no, since a rectangle requires 90-degree corners, and every angle inside an equilateral triangle is 60-degrees. The only multiple of 90 that you can make is 180-degrees (or any multiple of it). You can make rhombs, but no rectangles.

---

Getting funky and a bit creative, **yes**... in a way.

Since I don't know of any proper tools for this, I've used [Euclid: the game](http://euclidthegame.com/) for it. Here's a screenshot of the rectangle **CGJK** made from equilateral triangles, circles and intersections.

[image: screenshot]

**It occurs to me that only 3 triangles are needed since CEJ* is a rectangle, since CE is the radius of circle C, but CJ is shorter than that.** The answer below follows from before I noticed that, and thought you needed 5 triangles.

---

It uses a total of:

- 5 equilateral triangles

  - ABC
  - BCE
  - BEF
  - EFG
  - FGH
- 7 circles
- 2 points (A, B)
- 9 intersections (C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K)

To create it, you do the following (my mathematical notation is terrible, so this is just mostly English and not proper math-speak):

- Create any 2 points (A, B)
- Join them with a segment (AB)
- Plot a circle outwards from A to a radius of AB, likewise for B
- Plot points C and D where they meet
- Join C and D with a segment (I used a ray, but meh)

  - this creates the 2 right angles on the left hand side
- Create a circle outwards from C with a radius BC
- Plot point E on the intersection of B's circle and C's circle
- Create another equilateral triangle BCE
- Create a circle outwards from E with a radius EB
- Keep plotting intersections, triangles and circles until you get to H
- Plot intersection point I at the bottom intersection between the circles F and H
- Connect GI with a segment to create the right-hand edge of the rectangle
- Plot points J and K just to be neat

Comment: Wow! I'd like to see a better response then that, I would've accepted just the first part but +1 for getting creative! Well done!

Comment: I don't understand why this qualifies as creating rectangle from triangles.

Comment: @justhalf because the rectangle is composed entirely of triangles, and it's been constructed purely from geometry. It's possible to say with certainty that all the triangles are equilateral, and that the rectangle angles are correct, and that the tops and sides are different lengths. It's not the best question, since the actual answer is "no", but it's the closest you can get to a "yes"

Comment: Oh, also to clear one technicality up @justhalf, the question says the triangles must form the rectangle, and they must be equilateral. It doesn't say you can't use circles, points and segments to help you plot the triangles (although the vertical segments/rays is pushing it)

Comment: I mean, your rectangle is not formed by the triangles, but by the segments and rays, etc. Yes, you can use circles, points, segments, or rays to plot your triangles, but only the triangles should be counted for making up the rectangles. But OP accepts your answer, though. So my question is actually at OP, not on you :)

Comment: @justhalf I agree, it's not possible with just the triangle - my answer is basically a get-out-of-jail-free card for a question that doesn't have an interesting answer :P It was fun trying to think of something, though

Comment: Given this will only derail in 'out of the box' answers (the OP can only reap what sows), I figured I may aswell go for the lowest troll answer possible.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't say they can't overlap. I put a crude example - 5 triangles. Recall that a square is a *rectangle* whose sides are of equal length.

[image]

Think outside the equilateral triangle warspy

Comment: Lol that last statement :D

Comment: I knew you'd appreciate it lol

Comment: So, I could be overlooking something, but that should be 4 triangles. Right?

Comment: @Xrylite Yes :)  I just slapped an extra copy of the triangle on top - because we needed an odd number :p

Comment: @d'alar'cop I spent too long reading and thinking that I eventually discarded the 'odd' requirement. I knew it wouldn't be that simple to go through the work of creating the art, but mess up the structural answer. ^^

Comment: @Xrylite Well, I originally did it with 4... then I recalled that it was meant to be odd :p

Answer (score 6):

Another way of interpreting the question treats it as a classic Dudeney problem about dissections, with solution:

[image: Dissection of square and equilateral triangle]

Image from Wikimedia, released into the public domain by its creator.